# Clicking on Add Button , initializing a fieldset in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms

```
<Fieldset>
   <asp:table runat="server">
      <asp:TableRow runat="server">                 
         <asp:TableCell runat="server">
              <asp:DropDownList ID="Mark" runat="server"> </asp:DropDownList>
         </asp:TableCell>
         <asp:TableCell runat="server">
              <asp:DropDownList ID="visit" runat="server">
              </asp:DropDownList>
         </asp:TableCell>
      </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:table>
</Fieldset>

<asp:Button ID="Add" runat="server" Text="Add Rank" OnClick ="Adding" />
```

I don't know what should go on page behind code for onclick="Adding" method. When Clicking on the button "Add" I want the above fieldset to be generated on the form again. How do I achieve this in vb.net? any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't add any code then the form should be regenerated in the same state that you posted it, including everything within the fieldset

Comment: Clicking on the button is not doing anything.

Comment: It is posting back to the server and reinitialising the form in the same state - the form is being regenerated with all the data in that you posted

Comment: Well, let me make it clear. Clicking on the button should generate the fieldset again. which means the fieldset content should show up twice.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the Fieldset in a Repeater control. Bind the Repeater to a list. Add an item to the list for each additional Fieldset to be displayed.